# Syntax for Azure Cosmos DB CONTAINS

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following JSON Store on Azure Cosmos DB.

```
{
  "id": "4",
  "total": 10.46,
  "tax": 0.55,
  "soldItems": [
    {
      "item": "CHEESE NIPS 004400001300 F 1.97 D",
      "price": 1.97
    },
    {
      "item": "ROOT BEER 10.46",
      "price": 10.46
    }
    ]
}
```

and I am getting no results from this query:

```
SELECT * from c where CONTAINS(c.soldItems.item, "BEER")
```

What would be the correct syntax to check for a string in an JSON object value?

Comment: A bit confusing, but note that DocumentDb is now named CosmosDb!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c JOIN s in c.soldItems WHERE CONTAINS(s.item, "BEER")
```